# Can't find the declaration of variable 'this->'?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In tutorial [Intermediate: Connect to ROS](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i6)
[image: image description]

'this' is used as a variable or class, but I can't figure out how it declared.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18657/can%27t-find-the-declaration-of-variable-%27this-%3E%27-?/) by [littleghost](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4645/littleghost/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This C++ tutorial should help:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_this_pointer.htm

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2